Python regex convert single row into multiple rows
This is my data in single line.
1. B 2. E 3. E 4. D 5. E 6. A 7. A 8. E 9. E 10. D

How to convert into multiple lines as below using python
1. B
2. E
3. E
.
.
10. D


Try matching horizontal linebreaks that are followed by a digit \h+(?=\d) and replace with line breaks \n. See here

@DuesserBaest: Nice, but \h does not exist in Python's re dialect.

jup - see my answer; \s+ can be used as a substitute. using the regex module, you can make use of \h and many more regex functionalities.

Other than replacing each EOL (which would be the letters) with a \n, you can try this approach which takes each element consisting of a number, dot and letter and prints them in order:
import re

line = "1. B 2. E 3. E 4. D 5. E 6. A 7. A 8. E 9. E 10. D"

entries = re.findall(r'\d+\.\s[A-Z]', line)

for entry in entries:
    print(entry)

This is the output you should get:
1. B
2. E
3. E
4. D
5. E
6. A
7. A
8. E
9. E
10. D


As suggested in the comment try:
import re

line = "1. B 2. E 3. E 4. D 5. E 6. A 7. A 8. E 9. E 10. D"

res=re.sub("\s+(?=\d)","\n",line)
print(res)



\s+(?=\d): Matches spaces only when they occur before digits

\n: replace by newline



You can indeed use a regular expression to achieve this.
This python code uses regex to convert your string to the desired multi-line format as you want:
import re

my_string: str = "1. B 2. E 3. E 4. D 5. E 6. A 7. A 8. E 9. E 10. D"
# Use regex to find all occurrences of the pattern "number. letter"
matches = re.findall(r'\d+\.\s\w', data)
# Join the matches with newline characters; this creates the multi-lines
formatted_data = "\n".join(matches)

# Print the formatted data
print(formatted_data)

I'm using re.findall to find all occurrences of your specific pattern and then join them with the newline character \n to create the multiline support.
